# Keep world in ratio according to the resolution - screen size in LibGdx, Box2d

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d

I just started with LibGdx framework and I have a very first problem which I don't understand.
Since I want to make games from mobile devices I want to make my game look great on most resolutions (like most games do).

I've created some box2d stuff and tested it on 480x800 screen. It looks like this:

[image]

Then I've tested how it looks on 240x320 screen, and it doesn't look very well. The height of the ground should be smaller, also the box should be smaller. Additionaly there is one box missing (below the ground).

[image]

**What did I do until now:**

Well it is said that in box2d world 1pixel is 1meter which is not fine. So I create a constant with value 100, and I divided all box2d values (including orthographic camera) with this value. So what to do that box from 240x320 will be kept in ratio ( smaller screen - smaller world -> box and stuff ), and on highier resolutions the world will also be in ratio ( bigger resolution - bigger world -> box and stuff ).

I hope you understand the question. Thank in advance.

Comment: **Here's a hint:** 240x320 is 3:4, 480x800 is 3:5, since your 3s match the width looks okay but since 4 and 5 don't match your 240x320 has 1/10th cut off from the bottom and the top so you don't see the bottom box and also it looks like the box is not above the ground correctly (but actually its a part of the top sky that is not visible)

Comment: Have you seen the `ViewPort` classes in the nightlies. They can help you adjust the `Viewport` for every Screensize. Ofc there are always disadvantages: - The Viewport gets stretched, if aspect rations are different, game could look strage.  - You can see more of the world on big screens, which would be unfair in many games. - you have blackborders, to adjust the aspect ratio, its fair but looks stupid... Choose one of those possibilities.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason I've included some wrong variables in my Constatnts class.

```
public static int V_WIDTH = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
public static int V_HEIGHT = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();
```

Of course this was wrong because all measurements were wrong. (For example , World on 480x800 would be 48x80 meters , and on 240x320 device would be 24x32 meters )

When you define a game world you SHOULD specify some fixed screen resolution which you then set up your UI. If variables are fixed size, then world size on all resolutions is the same.

I've corrected above variables to:

```
public static int V_WIDTH = 480;
public static int V_HEIGHT = 800;
```

And now actually works. Game world resizes accordingly.

[image]

smaller resolution:

[image]